# Cambiar color según horas faltantes

Tags: angular, typescript

Hola como se puede en angular cambiar el color dependiendo las horas que falten para una hora especifica.

tengo asi:

```
<div class='col-11' *ngFor='let info of information' >
      <div>
        <div class='d-flex space-icon'>
          <span class='ml-1'>{{info.fechaFinal}}</span>
        </div>
        <span class='title'>{{info.titulo}}</span>
      </div>
     </div
</div>
```

esto lo que hace es devolverme información con la fecha incluyendo la hora de la siguiente manera:

```
2021-04-13T18:00:20.306Z
```

Lo que quiero es que si actualmente son las `2021-04-12T14:00:20.306Z` y faltan 4 horas para que sean las `18:00` pueda pintar esa hora de un color ejemplo azul y que si faltan 2 horas pintarla de rojo.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar ngClass.

En esta página tienes un ejemplo [Ejemplo de ngClass](https://www.angularjswiki.com/angular/how-to-add-a-class-based-on-condition-in-angular/)

En resumen, puedes añadir clases css condicionadas a la condición que tú crees

```html
<div [ngClass]="{'classname' : condition}"></div>
```

Posteriormente en tu fichero scss del componente defines las clases con los colores que le correspondan